# Print current time and date when a command is issued in linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, date, time

im trying to print the current time and date to the screen each time a command is issued on sift linux (ubuntu 14) via command line.

so for example

```
sansforensics@siftworkstation:$ fdisk -l image.dd 

sansforensics@siftworkstation:$ output of command

current time  and date 


sansforensics@siftworkstation:$
```

im not looking for

```
start_time=`date +%s`
<command-to-execute>
end_time=`date +%s`
echo execution time was `expr $end_time - $start_time` s.
```

which prints out the time it took for the commands to run, im looking for the current date and time each time a command is issued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `PROMPT_COMMAND` here:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='date'
```

As per `man bash`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND
     If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you! been trying to find this for an hour.